# How to host Website using Virtual Machine in Azure?

Tags: php, azure, xampp, virtual-machine, web-hosting

I have created a  virtual machine windows server 2012 on azure and I have bought a domain name from godaddy.com .My website folder is in htdocs folder of xampp. I have also created the virtual host in Virtual machine and I have given the IP address of it to the domain name. I am unable to figure out what to do next . Please help me out !

Answer (score 2):

If you web server is up and running in your VM you just need to open the external endpoints now.

From Azure portal >> Navigate to your VM >> Endpoints >> Add >> Type name, port and select protocol

For you custom domain, you have to go to godaddy dns manager and add a new host (A) entry pointing to your VM public ip.

Also make sure windows firewall is not blocking connections.

Comment: Using A DNS registries is not a good idea. It's better to create a CNAME record pointing to your xxxxx.cloudapp.net domain

Comment: depends on what your are trying to achieve. CNAME only works if you specify a hostname.

Comment: Deploying a VM inside Azure always has a cloud service associated that has a domain. If you point to the IP you can be in trouble if you stop or restart your cloud service, the IP can easily change if you don't set it as a static ip.