# Changing the host IP address in Flask to access it from outside

Tags: python, html, flask, ip, hostname

My application is hosted in Azure VM. I have created a static IP and a Public IP for the VM. Here are my steps.

1. Created the VM
2. Open the port 5000 using the inbound port rule.
3. Created a port forwarding rule in my router that has original port
   as 5000, the static IP of VM and the to port as 5000
4. Added my code and ran the program
5. Works with static IP

When I try to access it outside, it doesn't work. I have been on this for the whole day and still unable to figure out anything. Can you please guide here on how to access it outside of VM?

Below is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for
from flask import request


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['username'] != 'admin' or request.form['password'] != 'admin':
            error = "Invalid Credentials. Please try again."
        else:
            return render_template('link.html')

    return render_template('login.html',error = error)



if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host = 'static IP')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to host Website using Virtual Machine in Azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30959044/how-to-host-website-using-virtual-machine-in-azure)

Comment: Try this `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')`

Comment: You shouldn't be running a Flask app in production just via `app.run`. You need a proper server, eg gunicorn.